# How to refer to job IDs rather than names on Rundeck aclpolicy files?

Tags: rundeck

I can't seem to find anything that mentions how to use job IDs instead of names in aclpolicy files in Rundeck, as you can - very naturally - do in its API.

So instead of (slightly altered and shortened example from the API):

```
context:
  project: 'X'
for:
  job:
    - equals:
        group: 'adm'
        name: 'Restart'
      allow: [run,read]
```

I would like to have something like (notice the UUID instead of name):

```
context:
  project: 'X'
for:
  job:
    - equals:
        group: 'adm'
        id: '60b03f68-e023-4f90-982f-dd8ab36014ce'
      allow: [run,read]
```

Is it even possible to use job IDs at all here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a job UUID is a planned enhancement.

Comment: Thanks. Can you refer me to a place where I can bring this up for visibility? GitHub?